# Prove that given a path from points $x$ to $y$ there is a path from $y$ to $x$.

Tags: general-topology

It seems that some authors use this without proving it since it is sort of intuitively obvious, but I would like to show that in a space $X$, if there exists a path from $x$ to $y$ then there exists a path from $y$ to $x$.

Here is what I have so far. Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a path from $x$ to $y$ and consider the function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ given by $g(t) = f(1-t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Since $f(0) = x$ and  $f(1) = y$ then $g(0) = y$ and $g(1) = x$ as desired. It just remains to show that $g$ is continuous. Let $O \subset X$ be open. Then \begin{align*}g^{-1}(O) = \{t \in [0,1] : f(1-t)\in 0\} = \{x = 1-t \in [0,1]: f(x) \in O\}\end{align*}.

How do I  argue that $g^-1(O)$ is open?

Comment: $g$ is the composition of the continuous maps $t \mapsto 1-t$ and $f$.

Comment: ah. then just composition of continuous functions. thanks